# Como criar banco de dados via sql e utf8_bin?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho o seguinte script sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pais` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nome` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`sigla` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `pais` (`id`, `nome`, `sigla`) VALUES (1, 'Brasil', 'BR');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `estado` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uf` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pais` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_Estado_pais` (`pais`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;


INSERT INTO `estado` (`id`, `nome`, `uf`, `pais`) VALUES
(1, 'Acre', 'AC', 1),
(2, 'Alagoas', 'AL', 1),
(3, 'Amazonas', 'AM', 1),
(4, 'Amapá', 'AP', 1),
(5, 'Bahia', 'BA', 1),
(6, 'Ceará', 'CE', 1),
(7, 'Distrito Federal', 'DF', 1),
(8, 'Espírito Santo', 'ES', 1),
(9, 'Goiás', 'GO', 1),
(10, 'Maranhão', 'MA', 1),
```

Como vocês podem ver, coloquei CHARSET=utf8 e gera um banco com utf8_general_ci. E preciso que ela seja, apenas utf8_bin.
Já tentei colocar, no script, utf8_bin, mas ele aponta erro de sintáxe e diz que desconhece o utf8_bin.
Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Por que você quer isso?

Comment: A configuração de caracteres é UTF-8, a coleção (ou tabela) de caracteres que o MySQL usa como padrão é a utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Qual seu banco?

Comment: estou usandi MySQL

Comment: Mas só o banco, pois os campos eu posso tornar utf8_bin, certo?